# Is it safe to have subroutine with the same name in different fortran modules?

Tags: module, fortran, subroutine

I have written the following program and the output are as expected :

```
module mod1     
contains    
    subroutine print_mod1()
        call print_mod()
    end subroutine print_mod1
    
    subroutine print_mod()
        print *,'mod1'
    end subroutine print_mod        
end module mod1    

module mod2        
contains
    subroutine print_mod2()
        call print_mod()
    end subroutine print_mod2
    
    subroutine print_mod()
        print *,'mod2'
    end subroutine print_mod
end module mod2

program main
use mod1
use mod2

call print_mod1()
call print_mod2()

end program main
```

It works even if two subroutines (`print_mod`) have the same name in two different modules but they are never called from `main`.
I wonder if I could have in more complex program `unsuspected` behaviour ? In other words, should the line `private :: print_mod` be added in each module ?

Comment: The linked question is about variables and constants, but the same ideas hold for all module entities (including subroutines). You don't need to do anything special as long as you don't try to access the ambiguous name.

Comment: Perhaps this could be answered separately, saying whether the `private` statement is necessary or not. It likely is not. Whether it *should* be added is a different matter and largely a style issue. The problem is that one cannot just link a standard clause that would make it illegal, so one must say that there is none. There is no line in the standard that would explicitly say this exact thing is legal. The relevant section is "**19 Scope, association, and definition**" in F2018.